# using next to select multiple children of a particular html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a effect using jquery where one hovers over a side bar and it displays a navigation bar but the navigation itself has some effect properties so that when one clicks on one `dd` it shows the 3 children`dt`and hides the rest but currently it shows only the first dt and hides the rest...and why doesnt the close method work here is the code.

```
<html>
 <head>
<title></title>
<script src="Jquery.js">
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="nav">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <dd>One</dd>
            <dd>Two</dd>
            <dd>Three</dd>
        </dt>
        <dt>
            <dd>Four</dd>
            <dd>Five</dd>
            <dd>Six</dd>
        </dt>
        <dt>
            <dd>Seven</dd>
            <dd>Eight</dd>
            <dd>Nine</dd>
        </dt>
    </dl>
</div>  
<div class="sideBar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Sides={ 
   sideBar:$("div.sideBar"),
    nav:$("div.nav"),
    dd:$("div.nav dd"),
     dt:$("div.nav dt"),
     init:function  () {

    Sides.sideBar.on("mouseenter",this.show);
    },
    show:function  () {
    Sides.nav.close.call(nav);
    Sides.nav.fadeIn(2000).filter(":nth-child(n+8)").hide();
    Sides.dd.on("click",function  () {
        Sides.dd.next("dt").slideDown(500).siblings("dt").hide();
    })
  },
  close:function  () {
    Sides.nav.on("mouseleave",function  () {
        $(this).fadeOut(1400)
    })
    }
     }
       Sides.init();

  </script>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you asking why the 2nd and 3rd `<dt>` tags aren't being shown?

Comment: I don't really see any advantages of using an object literal like that, to just apply regular jQuery methods, and it would probably be a lot more readable and easier to trace errors if you just wrote it the regular way, and that's coming from a guy who loves object literals!

Comment: Looking at the quoted code, can I just say: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: yes why arent the 3rd and 4th `<dt>` not being shown

Comment: Incidentally, did you know that's not how `<dt>` and `<dd>` are supposed to be used? They should be siblings of each other inside the `<dl>`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing `})();` in your JavaScript code. It's causing JavaScript errors that prevent your code from being run.

Comment: the trailing })(); was from a self invoking function which i forgot to paste in while posting the question

Comment: Then please clean up the code in your question. If there is CSS needed, add that too. I can't tell from your code what is supposed to be going on.